# How do I set sublime text 3 columns to resize automatically on focus?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but here goes.

I want the column I'm currently working in to take up, say, 50% of the screen (I'm talking 3 column layout). But to grab the mouse and manually adjust the column width every single time I change working column is a pain.

How do I set things up so when I shift from column 1 to column 3, column 1 gets reduced from 50%->25% screen space, and column 3 goes 25%->50% (column 2 stays 25%)?

I'd love any help or even half solutions if possible. You may also tell me it's impossible, though that'll make me very sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was the [Origami](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami) plugin. By setting `"auto_zoom_on_focus" : 0.6,` in my user settings after installation, I now have the lovely auto re-sizing I desired :)

Edit: Thanks to @user10065308 for update on correct flag.

Comment: As MartinJH said the Origami plugin is the way to go.
But for actual version the flag you have to set up is:
{ "auto_zoom_on_focus" : 0.6
}

Comment: Thanks for the comment - updating my answer.